Ryobi Lithium+ 18V battery says fully charged but provides no energy
The lights on both the battery and the charger says it's fully charged.  However, the battery fails to power either of my Ryobi fans.  Both fans work just fine with my other Ryobi Lithium+ 18V batteries.

How old is the battery?

The battery is dead.   Sometimes there is a warranty and the manufacturer will replace it.

I've "jump started" batteries that wouldn't charge anymore, but it only works briefly.  Replace your battery.

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
